# I did not but why git deleted my files? How to fix it?

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I was working on a branch. I made tons of changes. When I finished my work, I added and committed. But when I tried to go back to master branch I saw my files was deleted. How could this possible ?

here my commit history.

```
 Mehmet@DESKTOP-DP8IB MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/comme (refactor)
$ gs
On branch refactor
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   app/Http/Controllers/DownloadsController.php
        modified:   app/Http/Controllers/ProductsController.php
        modified:   app/Product.php
        deleted:    database/factories/UserFactory.php
        modified:   database/migrations/2018_09_01_105020_create_products_table.                                                                                                                php
        modified:   resources/views/auth/agreement.blade.php
        modified:   resources/views/layouts/admin_app.blade.php
        modified:   resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php
        modified:   resources/views/layouts/left_sidebar.blade.php
        modified:   resources/views/layouts/top_nav.blade.php
        modified:   resources/views/products/create.blade.php
        modified:   resources/views/products/edit.blade.php
        modified:   resources/views/products/index.blade.php
        modified:   routes/web.php

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        app/Http/Controllers/ImagesController.php
        app/Image.php
        database/factories/ModelFactory.php
        database/migrations/2018_09_16_172536_create_images_table.php
        resources/views/layouts/colors_top_nav.blade.php
        resources/views/layouts/content_footer.blade.php
        resources/views/layouts/mega_top_nav.blade.php
        resources/views/layouts/menu_top_nav.blade.php
        resources/views/layouts/navigation_left_sidebar.blade.php
        resources/views/layouts/notifications_top_nav.blade.php
        resources/views/layouts/profile_left_sidebar.blade.php
        resources/views/products/add_modal.blade.php
        resources/views/products/edit_modal.blade.php

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

Mehmet@DESKTOP-DP8IB MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/comme (refactor)
$ gaa
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in app/Http/Controllers/ImagesController.ph                                                                                                                p.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in app/Image.php.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in database/migrations/2018_09_16_172536_cr                                                                                                                eate_images_table.php.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.

Mehmet@DESKTOP-DP8IB MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/comme (refactor)
$ git commit -m "Refactor & Create Image database"
[refactor b7ee8d9] Refactor & Create Image database
 26 files changed, 1372 insertions(+), 2017 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 app/Http/Controllers/ImagesController.php
 create mode 100644 app/Image.php
 rename database/factories/{UserFactory.php => ModelFactory.php} (86%)
 create mode 100644 database/migrations/2018_09_16_172536_create_images_table.ph                                                                                                                p
 create mode 100644 resources/views/layouts/colors_top_nav.blade.php
 create mode 100644 resources/views/layouts/content_footer.blade.php
 rewrite resources/views/layouts/left_sidebar.blade.php (95%)
 create mode 100644 resources/views/layouts/mega_top_nav.blade.php
 create mode 100644 resources/views/layouts/menu_top_nav.blade.php
 copy resources/views/layouts/{left_sidebar.blade.php => navigation_left_sidebar                                                                                                                .blade.php} (88%)
 create mode 100644 resources/views/layouts/notifications_top_nav.blade.php
 create mode 100644 resources/views/layouts/profile_left_sidebar.blade.php
 rewrite resources/views/layouts/top_nav.blade.php (89%)
 create mode 100644 resources/views/products/add_modal.blade.php
 create mode 100644 resources/views/products/edit_modal.blade.php
 rewrite resources/views/products/index.blade.php (87%)

Mehmet@DESKTOP-DP8IB MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/comme (refactor)
$ git log
commit b7ee8d9cc303345a9b0211f9ff0dd59 (HEAD -> refactor)
Author: Mehmet Dogan <mehmetd@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Sep 24 08:43:10 2018 +0300

    Refactor & Create Image database
```

gaa means git add .
gs means git status

```
    Mehmet@DESKTOP-DP8IB MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/comme (refactor)
$ git checkout master
fatal: cannot create directory at 'database/factories': Permission denied

Mehmet@DESKTOP-DP8IB MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/comme (refactor)
$ git status
On branch refactor
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   app/Http/Controllers/DownloadsController.php
        deleted:    app/Http/Controllers/ImagesController.php
        modified:   app/Http/Controllers/ProductsController.php
        deleted:    app/Image.php
        modified:   app/Product.php
        deleted:    database/factories/ModelFactory.php
        deleted:    database/migrations/2018_09_16_172536_create_images_table.php
        deleted:    resources/views/layouts/colors_top_nav.blade.php
        deleted:    resources/views/layouts/content_footer.blade.php
        deleted:    resources/views/layouts/mega_top_nav.blade.php
        deleted:    resources/views/layouts/menu_top_nav.blade.php
        deleted:    resources/views/layouts/navigation_left_sidebar.blade.php
        deleted:    resources/views/layouts/notifications_top_nav.blade.php
        deleted:    resources/views/layouts/profile_left_sidebar.blade.php
        deleted:    resources/views/products/add_modal.blade.php
        deleted:    resources/views/products/edit_modal.blade.php

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

Mehmet@DESKTOP-DP8IB MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/comme (refactor)
$ git checkout
M       app/Http/Controllers/DownloadsController.php
D       app/Http/Controllers/ImagesController.php
M       app/Http/Controllers/ProductsController.php
D       app/Image.php
M       app/Product.php
D       database/factories/ModelFactory.php
D       database/migrations/2018_09_16_172536_create_images_table.php
D       resources/views/layouts/colors_top_nav.blade.php
D       resources/views/layouts/content_footer.blade.php
D       resources/views/layouts/mega_top_nav.blade.php
D       resources/views/layouts/menu_top_nav.blade.php
D       resources/views/layouts/navigation_left_sidebar.blade.php
D       resources/views/layouts/notifications_top_nav.blade.php
D       resources/views/layouts/profile_left_sidebar.blade.php
D       resources/views/products/add_modal.blade.php
D       resources/views/products/edit_modal.blade.php
```

Why this files deleted? I dont know. Can I recover them? Any help appreciated.. I am so scared :(

Comment: What are "my files" here?  Were they untracked files which you did not commit, or something else?

Comment: I don't know too much about git. This the first time I have use. What is untracked files means?  I did not delete anything. I just made changes and use gaa for adding everything. What should I do now?

Comment: You've posted a mess and I don't have time to read through it.  _Which_ files were deleted?  Were these files committed?  Do you understand that if you created files on the branch which did _not_ exist in `master`, then these files will disappear when you switch back to `master`?

Comment: Alright, let me explain. Those untacked files deleted. I was on the refactor branch. I did many changes on refactor branch. Then, I add everything. All of this changed files was on refactor branch. I would try to merge this file so I tried to change refactor branch to master branch. But git did not allowed me. After that I checked my files and I saw it was reverted.

Comment: Ahh, May Git ignored my files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following for restoring your branch:

```
git stash -u
```

(this will stash everything you have - so you'll be able to restore it back later in case of a problem)

and then:

```
git checkout refactor
```

(this will restore your branch where you committed your files)

After that, you can validate that your commit is there by running:

`git log`

Comment: Why can't the OP just run `git log refactor` from the `master` branch without going to all the trouble of stashing?  Also, we don't really know if the OP really even has a problem.

Comment: because the git log command is just for validating that the restore went ok. The restore of the branch is the main issue in my answer

Comment: Is it the same with "git checkout -- <filename> " ? I am trying to revert this way. for each file.It is working and than I will amend the previous commit. Is it wrong ?  Thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: seems wrong to me. This is not SVN - GIT works as snapshots of the whole repository and not revision per file, so I won't recommend this method.
Since - according to your snapshot - the files were successfully committed in the branch, the best way to recover the files is to checkout the branch, as I described in the answer.

Comment: Do you have an idea why would that be ?